# R: how to re-scale plots?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using R with R-Studio. How can I re-scale the axis of a plot I made using `plot(...)`? The only option I see at this point is to Zoom in, which pretty much displays the dame graph on the entire screen..

EDIT:
I will explain better the use case I'm looking for:
Assume I'm plotting the next graph: `plot(c(1,2),c(3,4))`. This will yield the following graph:
[image: Sample plot]
Then I want to add another point: `points(1,5)`. Since the new point is beyond the axis boundaries, I cannot see it. How can I re-scale the axis so I can see all the points (without replotting everything)?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by rescale?  Are you trying to output the plot? Are you just trying to change the x axis labels? Please clarify this in your question.

Comment: you might be interested in the [playwith package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/playwith/index.html)

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible. You need to set the limits on the first plot command.

Answer (score 1):

If by re-scale you mean to only display part of `x`-axis or `y`-axis, then you can add:

```
xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10)
```

This will only display point between 0 to 10 for the `x`- and `y`- axes. You can choose what values you wish to be displayed.

Comment: @shakedzy please accept the answer if that solved your problem.

Comment: This is not what I meant. I would like to do this after the plot has already been drawn.